# A/B (Split) testing the shopping cart in Magento

Tags: magento, ab-testing

We would like to implement A/B (or split) testing on our shopping cart in Magento.

The new design is enough of a departure from the existing one, that we cannot easily create the test using something like Visual Web Optimizer. The only way we would be able to do something with VWO is to create two different URLs for the cart, displaying the original one in the normal `/checkout/cart` and the new one in `/checkout/shoppingcart` - or something like that.

Is it possible to do something like this within Magento or am I going to delve deeper into the code?

One possible solution I was looking at was (doing a really dodgy hack) copying the CartController.php and creating a new controller called ShoppingcartController.php. I'm not a fan of this, it's just way to dodgy...but as it's going to be throw away code, I think I'd be able to sleep at night ;)

I'm completely lost as how I could do this. Ultimately, it would be great if I could create two front routes, pointing back to the same controller...but I don't think Magento is that flexible.

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this, is to create two "views" (under one website), and use different URL's for each view, such as: www.site.com www1.site.com.

Once this is set up have Google's A/B testing functionality (or some other JS) direct users to the different views.

Good luck!